# Selenium WebDriver + Java -- Element not visible

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am starting out with Selenium WebDriver and trying to automate the UI testing of the following site: https://retirementtools.legalandgeneral.com/an_form.cfm.

On the second page, I'm unable to get it to click on the "Save and Continue" button (it works fine on the landing page and I've already got the code to make the selection of the provider on the first page to proceed. That all works fine).

The HTML for this button is:

```
<a href="javascript:tabButtonClick(1)" onclick="$(this).addClass('clicked')" id="nextBtn" class="nextBtn button blue align-right">Save and Continue</a>
```

I started off just trying to use findElement and the ID with the following code but no luck:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("nextBtn")).click();
```

I've tried changing this to find by CSS selector and XPath, also no luck.

I've added in waits to make sure the element has loaded, didn't help.

I've also tried adding a scroll, but that didn't seem to help either.

The Save and Continue button appears multiple times within the page but each has a different ID so I assume that isn't stopping it from working?

As I mentioned, I'm quite new to this so apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

Many thanks!

Comment: what was your expath code? and what was the result?

Comment: Did you share your current code? I am trying to see where did you start and where it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the element with XPath for the text containing within the tag. But don't understand the reason why it can't find by id.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Save and Continue')]"));
```

**Edit:**

According to your comment, the page contains more than one element whose id is `nextBtn`. If so, you can do in another way:

```
List <WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.id("nextBtn")); //getting the list of element whose id is 'nextBtn'
int size = elements.size(); //getting the size of the list
elements.get(size-1).click(); //clicking on the last element of the list
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that didn't work either for me. However i found the following solution on another site (though to be honest i don't wholey understand what it's doing:                                  `int ok_size=driver.findElements(By.id("nextBtn")).size();
          driver.findElements(By.id("nextBtn")).get(ok_size-1).click();`

Comment: Oh. That means the page have at least two link which id is nextBtn. See my edited code. I searched for 'Save and continue' instead of 'Save and Continue'. See whether this works or not.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear why you did not find element, so I am going to guess here. It seems until you select an option, the form will not submit. So I assume you did not select an option

So first you need to select an option

`driver.findElement(By.id("mainfund_sloc")).click();`

Then you have to click on the `Save and Continue`

`driver.findElement(By.id("nextBtn")).click();`

Comment: Hi, thanks sorry i should have mentioned i'd already made that selection. The findElement using ID still doesn't work. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

To click on the button with text as **Save and Continue** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* and invoke `click()` method as follows :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
// lines of code
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#details_navigation>a"))).click();
```

You can get more granular and can use :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
// lines of code
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#details_navigation>a.nextBtn.button.blue.align-right"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Locating element with only id won't help in this situation try by following
Since there are multiple elements with same ID in dom

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'Click(1)') and @id='nextBtn']"));
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code,it worked for me.
May be It would help you

```
public class Demo_Test {
    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://retirementtools.legalandgeneral.com/an_form.cfm");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"chooseApplicantAdditionalSmokertype\"]/div[2]/div[2]/label")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"nextBtn\"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"st_link_button\"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[22]/a")).click();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like what is below? This is assuming that you yourself cannot actually see the button. If you can't see it, then sometimes selenium cannot see it. Therefore, you have to scroll to the item first: 
**Option 1**

```
execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",element)
```

**Option 2**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_element_by_id("my-id")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that a good technique for dealing with multiple versions of the same element where one is always visible and the others are always hidden is to collect all of them, and loop through until we find the visible one.

```
    @Test
public void exampleTest() {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://retirementtools.legalandgeneral.com/an_form.cfm");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Legal & General']")).click();

    findVisibleContinueButton(driver).click();

    // Sleep just because I don't want to fill out all the fields, your code should not need this
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // ... fill your other fields

    findVisibleContinueButton(driver).click();
}

public WebElement findVisibleContinueButton(WebDriver driver) {
    ArrayList<WebElement> continueButtons = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.id("nextBtn"));

    for(WebElement continueButton : continueButtons) {
        if(continueButton.isDisplayed()) {
            return continueButton;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

While I was testing, the second button ended up being quite finicky, and I had to click it twice.  Not sure the reason for this, but be aware the form may not be behaving too well under automation.

This code should be usable at all stages of the form as long as each continue button has the nextBtn ID on it.